# Finding the maximum volume of a tetrahedron with 3 concurrent edges

Tags: geometry

Can someone help me out? I am not good at math. Thank you.

> Find the maximum volume of the tetrahedron that have three concurrent edges and satisfy the following condition:
>
> The sum of three edges is constant.
>
> One edge is double the length of another edge.

I found a formula to calculate an irregular tetrahedron without having to know the height but I have no idea how to know which volume is larger since the given formula is in a matrix format. Am I heading to the right direction on this question?

The source of formula (very new here, don't know how to insert matrix):
[http://mathforum.org/dr.math/faq/formulas/faq.irreg.tetrahedron.html#:~:text=It%20is%20irregular%20if%20and,not%20all%20of%20equal%20measure](http://mathforum.org/dr.math/faq/formulas/faq.irreg.tetrahedron.html#:%7E:text=It%20is%20irregular%20if%20and,not%20all%20of%20equal%20measure).

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Have you tried optimisation?

Comment: Among tetrahedra with concurrent edges $x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3$, the one with maximal volume clearly(?) has those edges at right angles to each other. Such a tetrahedron has volume $\frac16x_1x_2x_3$. The problem, therefore, reduces to maximizing that product, subject to the conditions you have provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you operate with the relations between $x_1,x_2,x_3$ you are given, you can define the volume $V$ in function of $x_2$ this way:
$$
x_1=2x_2 \phantom{a},\phantom{a} x_2=x_2 \phantom{a},\phantom{a} x_3=L-3x_2.
$$
So you en up with the volume being (it is $V=\frac{1}{6}x_1x_2x_3$ because that's the maximal volume formula for the irregular tetrahedron, with the edges making right angles between them):
$$
V(x_2)=\frac{1}{6}x_1\cdot x_2\cdot x_3=\frac{1}{3}Lx^2_2-x^3_2.
$$
If you derivate this expression, you end up with
$$
V'(x_2)=x_2\left(\frac{2L}{3}-3x_2\right).
$$
The equation $V'(x_2)=0$ gives you two solutions, one is obviously $x_2=0$, but that's the minimun, not what we want. The other solution is the maximun, which is $\boxed{x_2=\frac{2L}{9}}$.
This gives us the final results:

$$\boxed{x_1=\frac{4L}{9},\quad x_2=\frac{2L}{9},\quad x_3=\frac{L}{3}}.$$
$$\boxed{V=\frac{1}{6}\frac{8L^3}{3^5}=\frac{4L^3}{3^6}}$$

Tell me if there's anything you don't understand from my solution, I'll try to explain it to you.

Comment: The volume of a tetrahedron is not given by the product of three concurrent edges (just as the area of a triangle is not given by the product of two adjacent edges). It is true that the maximal volume occurs when the edges all make right angles, but in that case the volume is $\frac16x_1x_2x_3$.

Comment: Oh, I thought is was a prism, I'll do it again and edit it.

Comment: The volume formula for an irregular tetrahedron is a lot more complicated and can be expressed in matrix. You can take it up from there.

Comment: @MathLover So isn't my answer valid?

Comment: No it is not valid. You are using formula for a tri-rectangular tetrahedron to start with. We cannot assume it is.

Comment: @AlejandroBergasaAlonso Thanks for your answer, the first sentence did help me.

Comment: @Mooneve Your welcome. I'm sorry for it being a non perfect answer due to assuming $V=\frac{1}{6}x_1x_2x_3$.

Comment: The volume of an irregular tetrahedron can also be written as $\frac{abc}{6}\sqrt{1+2cos\alpha cos\beta cos\gamma - cos^2\alpha-cos^2\beta-cos^2\gamma}$, which will be maximum when $\alpha = \beta = \gamma = 90^0$. So you are right about it being a tri-rectangular tetrahedron for maximum volume. So your solution is right. Please fix the typo in the last line - you have written $L^2$ instead of $L^3$.

Comment: @AlejandroBergasaAlonso I have just validated. Your answer is right. Read my last comment to see why your volume assumption is right.

Comment: @MathLover I've corrected the error. Thanks for your support!

Comment: @MathLover: You can get to the trirectangular-is-maximal result simply by observing that the volume of any tetrahedron is improved by adjusting one of its edges at a vertex to be perpendicular to the plane of the other two edges. (After all, this maximizes the "height" relative to the "base" triangle that plane.) So, adjusting $x_1$ to be perpendicular to the plane of $x_2$ and $x_3$, and then adjusting $x_2$ to be perpendicular to the plane of $x_3$ and (the previously-adjusted) $x_1$ completely maximizes volume by creating three mutually-perpendicular edges in a trirectangular tetrahedron.

Comment: Yes I know that but when you increase the angle between a plane between two edges and the opposite edge from the same vertex such that $0^0 \lt \theta \lt 180^0$, the area of the base increases and the height decreases. So you kind of know it but cannot be sure it is maximum at right angle just by observing. That is why I checked it once.

Comment: @MathLover: *"So you kind of know it but cannot be sure it is maximum at right angle just by observing.*" ... Indeed, you *can* be sure. While edge $x_1$ is being moved into position perpendicular to plane of edges $x_2$ and $x_3$, those other two edges remain fixed, as does the area of the "base" triangle they determine; the volume *strictly* increases (unless we had perpendicularity from the start). Then, while $x_2$ moves, the edges $x_3$ and (the moved) $x_1$ remain fixed, as does the area of *their* "base" triangle; volume strictly increases again. Happily, there's no need for a 3rd step.

Comment: But if you keep the base and two edges fixed, you are changing the length of $x_1$ as you change the angle. So you do not know for sure. If you keep all $x_1, x_2$ and $x_3$ fixed, you are changing the area of the base. Either way you do not know for sure.

Comment: @MathLover: *"But if you keep the base and two edges fixed, you are changing the length of $x_1$ as you change the angle."* What? No. Edge $x_1$ *maintains its length* as it moves to be perpendicular, obviously(?) making the tetrahedron taller relative to the fixed base, and thus increasing the volume. (Just as a triangle with fixed-length sides $a$ and $b$ will have maximal area when those edges are perpendicular.) ... *"If you keep all $x_1$, $x_2$ and $x_3$ fixed, you are changing the area of the base."* This is nonsense that I don't know how to address; I'll stop trying. Good luck to you.

Comment: @Blue Please think of a triangle with two fixed sides. If you change the angle, the length of the diagonal edge would change, right? Coming to this, you keep the base fixed. You keep two edges $x_2$ and $x_3$ same. Now you are moving the plane made by $x_3$, $x_2$ and one of the edges of the base wrt. $x_1$, hinging on the base edge. As the angle between the plane and $x_1$ change, of course $x_1$ cannot remain fixed. Its length has to change. My humble request to think through it.

Comment: Also I do not appreciate your language. There is no reason to use words like "nonsense".  Thank you.

Comment: @MathLover: It's "nonsense" because it's *nonsensical*. Consider the tetrahedron w/vertices $O=(0,0,0)$, $X_2=(1,0,0)$, $X_3=(0,1,0)$, $X_1=(1,1,1)$. The base in the $xy$-plane is a triangle w/area  $\frac12$; the height relative to that base is $X_1$'s distance to the plane: $1$. If I move $\overline{OX_1}$ to be perpendicular to the $xy$-plane, *while keeping its length* ($\sqrt3$), it aligns with the $z$-axis such that $X_1$ falls at $(0,0,\sqrt3)$. The area of the $xy$-base *remains* $1/2$, as its sides were unaffected. The height relative to that base is now $\sqrt3>1$; volume got bigger.

Comment: But if you are keeping $OX_1$ fixed as it aligns with Z axis, it falls at $(0,0,\sqrt{3})$ 
which changes (increases) the length of the edges $X_2X_1$ and $X_3X_1$ from $\sqrt{2}$ each to 2 each. So of course the volume changes. Please see earlier posts where we were discussing edges remaining the same. Thank you.

Comment: @MathLover: We were discussing edges *concurrent at a point* remaining the same. In  my $OX_1X_2X_3$ tetrahedron example, concurrent edges $OX_i$ keep their length; whatever happens with $X_2X_1$ and $X_3X_1$ is completely irrelevant. ... ("Extended discussion" warning. I won't be commenting further.)

Comment: If you are taking concurrent edges from O then the base is opposite it, which is changing. Anyway, let's leave. Thanks for the discussion.

Comment: @MathLover: (Okay. *One last comment.*) The base of a tetrahedron can be any face one prefers, and I wrote explicitly and (I thought) unambiguously from the beginning that, when moving $x_1$, my preferred "base" was in the plane determined by the *"other two edges"* (ie, $x_2$ and $x_3$), so that the adjustment of $x_1$ to be perpendicular to that plane *"maximizes the 'height' relative to the 'base' triangle [in] that plane"*. I'm not sure how I could have made that any clearer, but I suppose that's just a failure of imagination on my part. ... Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for your last comment. I misunderstood which edges you were referring to in yesterday's comments.

Answer (score 1):

Let us consider a reference system in which the concurrent edges are located in the origin $O$ of the reference, the $OA=x_1$ edge lays on the $x$-axis, the $OB=x_2$ edge lays on the $xy$ coordinate plane and the $OC=x_3$ edge is located in the half-space $z>0$, as in the figure.
Let's call $\alpha$ the angle between the edges $x_1$ and $x_2$ and $\beta$ the angle between the edge $x_3$ and the plane $xy$.

[image]

Then
\begin{align}
V(x_2,\alpha,\beta) &= \frac{1}{3}Ah=\frac{1}{3}\left[\frac{1}{2}\overline{OA}\cdot\overline{OB}\sin\alpha\right]OC\sin\beta\\
  &= \frac{1}{3}\left[\frac{1}{2}2x_2\cdot x_2\sin\alpha\right](L-3x_2)\sin\beta\\
  &= \frac{1}{3}x_2^2(L-3x_2)\sin\alpha\sin\beta
\end{align}
then, to look for the maximum we have
\begin{align}
  \frac{\partial V}{\partial x_2}   &= \frac{1}{3}x_2(2L-9x_2)\sin\alpha\sin\beta\\
  \frac{\partial V}{\partial\alpha} &= \frac{1}{3}x_2^2(L-3x_2)\cos\alpha\sin\beta\\
  \frac{\partial V}{\partial\beta}  &= \frac{1}{3}x_2^2(L-3x_2)\sin\alpha\cos\beta
\end{align}
from which we have $\alpha=\beta=\pi/2$ and $x_2=2L/9$.